# How to store the_title() into a variable to reutrn the value, not just echo it

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I have a loop, and need to pass one more argument through it. I need to get the current page's single post title, and then use that as the value.

I tried going about it like this:

```
$tagz = the_title();

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'product_tag' => "{$tagz}"  );
```

and the `$tagz` variable just automatically echo's the current post title. I found out through this resource [this resource](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) that `the_title()` merely echos the title and never returns it, making the `$tagz` variable null.

How can I use the current posts title as an argument? I am really stumped!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use the right parameter for `the_title()` as Jon Stirling suggested, or do the following:

```
$tagz = get_the_title();
```

> `get_the_title()`
>
> This function will return the title of a post for a given post ID.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: You have to specify the post ID, though. It does not work for dynamic content.

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. According to docs regarding parameter `$ID`: *"The ID of the post or an object that specifies the post from which to get the title. By default the current post is fetched."* If you do not pass a parameter, it will return the current post's title.

Comment: oh wow it does work XD never-mind. My previous comment was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I reread the resource like Jon suggested. It turnes out `$tagz = the_title('','',false);` works perfectly.